# You attempted to import module which falls outside of the project

Tags: reactjs, react-scripts

I created react app and when I try to build it I got error

```
Module not found: Error: You attempted to import /home/runner/work/my-project/my-project/node_modules/querystring-es3/index.js which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/.
```

when I run  `npm ls querystring-es3`
I see it is part of react-scripts
what can be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think your path is wrong.. You might have imported it from another node_modules